Render List using ListView.builder
I am trying to render list of cards in flutter, but i am getting exception
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
import 'package:ServiceDispatch/core/widgets/job_card.dart';

import '../../core/utils/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'home_with_tasks_screen_logic.dart';
import '../../core/widgets/index.dart';

class HomeWithTasksScreenView extends GetView<HomeWithTasksScreenLogic> {
  const HomeWithTasksScreenView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
      appBar: CommonWidgets.commonAppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.h,
            ),
            Obx(() {
              return CommonWidgets.commonScreenSwitchButton(
                  isActiveScreen: controller.isActiveScreen);
            }),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16.w,
                right: 16.w,
                top: 10.h,
                bottom: 20.h,
              ),
              child: Obx(() {
                if (controller.isActiveScreen.value == true) {
                  return JobCard(
                    jobDetails: controller.jobDetails,
                    commentData: controller.commentData,
                    icons: controller.icons,
                    serviceDetails: controller.serviceDetails,
                    hasAcknowledged: controller.hasAcknowledged,
                    hasArrived: controller.hasArrived,
                    hasDeparted: controller.hasDeparted,
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return JobCard(
                      jobDetails: controller.completedJobs[index],
                      commentData: controller.commentData,
                      icons: controller.icons,
                    );
                  });
                }
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

My JobCard widget is fine because if i remove ListView.builder then a single card renders perfectly, i know this is some layout issue, but i can't seem to solve it.
Please suggest what i am doing wrong.
Thanks everyone.

Found The issue!! I am using ListView.builder(), inside SingleChildScrollView() due to which the error occured. i replaced my ListView.builder() with map and everything worked fine.
